# how to compare a pandas column to a number and select the smaller one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to do some calculations and wrote code like:

```
col_median = data['col'].median()
data['col'] = data['col'].apply(lambda x:10+min(5, ((x-col_median)/col_median))*20,
axis=1)
```

and I got error ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

I want to do this calculation to each column of a dataframe:
10 + min(5,((data-column median)/column median))*20

Comment: Please use correct upper case letters.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Vectorize your operations:

```
import numpy as np

data['col'] = 10+np.minimum(5, ((data['col']-col_median)/col_median))*20
```

Answer (score 0):

The equation min(5, ((x-col median)/col median))*20 does not produce a single boolean value as needed by the apply() method.

You can change the lambda function's return type from a Pandas Series to a scalar value to correct this mistake.

```
col_median = data['col'].median()
data['col'] = data['col'].apply(lambda x: 10 + min(5, ((x-col_median)/col_median))*20)
```

This allows you to compute the precedence system  for each output in the 'col' column and save the effect further down in the same column.

```
for col in data.columns:
    col_median = data[col].median()
    data[col] = data[col].apply(lambda x: 10 + min(5, ((x-col_median)/col_median))*20)
```

The formula will be computed using the column median in a loop that traverses each column in the DataFrame, and the output will be saved back in the original column.